# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataSet'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I've been trying to name a set of parameters that are working with a function from other class. Everything's working well but I'm getting troubles from the last parameter **dtsBank["Events"]**. It just keeps telling me "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataSet'".

```
DataSet dtsBank = new DataSet();
msg = Function.Fill_Dataset("QUINTA", dtsBank, "Events", 
"Load_Catalogs", "EventType,1", "@vchTable,@intStatus", 
dtsBank["Events"]);
```

Comment: I am not aware of `DataSet` having indexing...

Comment: On this line, dtsBank is still an empty DataSet. So what do you expect `dtsBank["Events"]` to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the DataTable stored in the DataSet, you'll need to use the `DataSet.Tables` property. You cannot apply indexing to the DataSet object.

You can find more info about DataSet here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the .Tables property.